# Can I do a binary search on an array of objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, binary-search-tree

I am currently learning how to use searching and sorting algorithms and I am running into issues with a binary search on an array of objects of customers' data. The array of customers is sorted by first and last name.

The goal is to find a customer's email and return the index.

The data looks like:

```
[
  {
    "username": "Maude.Torp",
    "email": "Taya.Kerluke53@gmail.com",
    "address": {
      "street": "Rowe Fields",
      "suite": "Suite 231",
      "city": "Tiannamouth",
      "zipcode": "07584-6653",
      "geo": { "lat": "75.0283", "lng": "-17.1824" }
    },
    "phone": "795-827-5446 x18366",
    "website": "nico.com",
    "company": {
      "name": "Champlin, Feest and Barrows",
      "catchPhrase": "Object-based user-facing orchestration",
      "bs": "transition integrated content"
    },
    "firstName": "Maida",
    "lastName": "Feeney"
  },
  ...
]
```

My binary search function looks like:

```
function searchByEmail(email, customers) {
  let start = 0;
  let end = customers.length - 1;

  while (start <= end) {
    let middle = Math.floor((start + end) / 2);

    if (customers[middle] === email) {
      return middle;
    } else if (customers[middle] < email) {
      start = middle + 1;
    } else {
      end = middle - 1;
    }
  }
  return -1;
}
```

On a sorted array of numbers I am able to return the index of the desired key.

```
let customers = [1, 10, 45, 56, 66, 567]
...
console.log(searchByEmail(66, customers))

// --> 4
```

When I look through this array of objects I only return -1. How do I change this algorithm to work for objects within arrays?

Comment: Is the array of customers sorted by the email address? That is what you would need to be able to do a binary search on the email.

Comment: Right, same as I was about to say :)

Comment: Also note that if you get that big array from a database, you may want to query it with some filter, instead of retrieving all customers and then finding one or more from the complete list

Comment: @Zorgatone Awesome, I appreciate it. You've been super helpful!

Comment: @alexwhitmore you're welcome

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to binary search the customer array, provided that it's ordered by customer email.

Change the code up a bit to compare the email instead of the entire object, accessing the email property of the object.

```
function searchByEmail(email, customers) {
  let start = 0;
  let end = customers.length - 1;

  while (start <= end) {
    let middle = Math.floor((start + end) / 2);

    // NOTE the ".email" part added
    if (customers[middle].email === email) {
      return middle;
    } else if (customers[middle].email < email) {
      start = middle + 1;
    } else {
      end = middle - 1;
    }
  }
  return -1;
}
```

Comment: That adjustment makes sense. How would this function change if it was sorted by first and last name as opposed to being sorted by email?

Comment: It would not find the results correctly. The array must be sorted by the key on which you’d like to binary search

Comment: If it’s not sorted by email, you can sort it and then do the binary search. It should still be better than going through the whole array I think (depending on the sorting algorithm ofc)

Comment: In the best case, sorting requires N*log(N) steps. In the worst case, a search requires N steps. Sorting an array just to search is useless imo

Comment: Yeah. That's true. It doesn't make sense to sort the array first if we just want to search for an element in it, unless ofcourse, we are able to use bucket sort or something similar and sort the array in O(n)

Comment: If you will be doing more than one search it would be worth it though

Comment: Careful with this if you're using umlauts (e.g. German ones like "ä"). In my case umlauts have to be at the end of the list that I give my JavaScript code (so after "z"), otherwise this binary search won't find the word and will return "-1" incorrectly.

Answer (score 1):

You can add binary search method to `Array.prototype` and use it as [lower_bound](https://cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/lower_bound/) or [upper_bound](https://cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/upper_bound/) c++ equivalents. The method of array prototype will return the nearest index of an element in array.

Here is my implementation:

```js
Array.prototype.binarySearch = function(elem, compare = (a, b) => a < b) {
  let left = 0;
  let right = this.length;

  while (left != right - 1) {
    const mid = Math.floor((left + right) / 2);
    if (compare(this[mid], elem)) {
      left = mid;
    } else {
      right = mid;
    }
  }

  return left + compare(this[left], elem);
};

// sorted array
const arr = [
  { age: 10, name: 'nick'},
  { age: 20, name: 'john'},
  { age: 30, name: 'aaron'},
  { age: 30, name: 'ana'},
  { age: 30, name: 'ana'},
  { age: 30, name: 'casandra'},
  { age: 40, name: 'dave'}, 
  { age: 40, name: 'jake'},
  { age: 50, name: 'pablo'}
];

// search by age

const lowByAge = arr.binarySearch({ age: 30 }, (a, b) => a.age < b.age);
console.log('lower_bound (age):', lowByAge); // lower_bound (age): 2

const upByAge = arr.binarySearch({ age: 30 }, (a, b) => a.age <= b.age);
console.log('upper_bound (age):', upByAge); // upper_bound (age): 6

// search by age and name

const lowByAgeAndName = arr.binarySearch({ age: 30, name: 'ana' }, (a, b) => 
    (a.age == b.age) ?  a.name < b.name : a.age < b.age);
console.log('lower_bound (age, name):', lowByAgeAndName); // lower_bound (age, name): 3

const upByAgeAndName = arr.binarySearch({ age: 30, name: 'ana' }, (a, b) => 
    (a.age == b.age) ?  a.name <= b.name : a.age < b.age);
console.log('upper_bound (age, name):', upByAgeAndName); // upper_bound (age, name): 5
```

Then you can use this method in any function you want.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the above answers,

Yes, We can do binary search on a sorted array of objects. But it's not the best way when it's unsorted.

If array is unsorted then you need to do 2 steps.

1. You need to sort it first (Complexity O(n))
2. You need to implement binary search(Complexity  O(n))

Total complexity for above steps is O(n*n)

But to unsorted array you need to go with linear search and the complexity is O(n)

So Considering array of objects and if its sorted.

Then instead of comparing each value we are going to access and compare a value which is inside the object. Remaining algorithm is as same as in Binary search.